# Query for existence of multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I need to write a query that will return results if all the tables I'm asking for exist. I know this exists:

```
show tables like 'user'
```

Just not sure how to extend that for multiple tables. I know this is invalid code, but something like

```
show tables like 'user' AND show tables like 'site' AND ...
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can use the information_schema.tables object - see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * 
from information_schema.tables
where table_name in ('tb1','tb2','tb3') 
and table_schema = 'your_db'
having count(table_name) = 3
```

Mmm, I realised there was a problem with that query. It returns just one record if all the tables exist. This would be a better solution

```
select group_concat(table_name order by table_name) as table_list
from information_schema.tables
where table_name in ('tb1','tb2','tb3') 
and table_schema = 'your_db'
having count(*) = 3
```

Comment: Stack overflow is a magical place. Holy crap this answer was fast! Thank you!!

Comment: @elightbo: don't worry. Glad I could help you. Regards. :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this works in MySQL... (just an example)

```
SHOW TABLES WHERE Tables_in_<database-name> IN ([<table-names-comma-separated>])
```

Example:

```
SHOW TABLES WHERE Tables_in_YourDB IN ('users', 'sites')
```